# Perl: store multi-valued cmd line argument directly into hash keys

Tags: perl, hash, getopt-long

I'm adding some command line parsing to a Perl script and I'm trying to figure out how to store the multiple values of a single command line argument as keys of a hash.

The following MWE hopefully gets at what I want to do.

```
# foo.pl    
use Data::Dumper;

use Data::Dumper::Simple;
use Getopt::Long;

my %opt=();

my @tempSuppress;

GetOptions ('verbose' => \$opt{verbose},
            'suppress:s{1,}' => \@tempSuppress,
            );

print "@tempSuppress\n";


my $tempvar = shift @tempSuppress;
$opt{suppress}{$tempvar}=1;
$tempvar = shift @tempSuppress;
$opt{suppress}{$tempvar}=1;
# Yes, the above 4 lines could be in a loop

warn Dumper(%opt);

if($opt{verbose}){
    print "Some verbose output\n";
}

if(!$opt{suppress}{E}){
    print "Some default output you can suppress with option suppress value 'E'\n";
}

if(!$opt{suppress}{F}){
    print "Some other default output you can suppress with option suppress value 'F'\n"
}
```

As you can see from my demo print statements, I'd like to be able to use the various keys of `%opt` as booleans to enable/disable various sections of the code. Pretty straightforward I think.

There are also a couple different types of output that generally will be on by default, but I want the option to suppress it. I have the argument `suppress` that can take multiple values to denote which types to suppress, e.g. you might run `foo.pl --suppress E F`.

I was hoping to have each of them become a hash key as well so it would still be quick & easy to refer to them, as I've done later in my code.

After reading the documentation on [options with multiple values](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-multiple-values), I see how to store those two values into an array, and as you can see in my code, I can copy them out into sub-keys of the `suppresss` key in `opt`. I was hoping that that process of getting them into those sub-keys could be integrated into the call to `GetOptions`, e.g. something like the following:

```
GetOptions ('verbose' => \$opt{verbose},
            'suppress:s{1,}' => \$opt{suppress},
            );
```

But after trying that, I see it just gives the `suppress` key of `opt` the value of the last value processed (e.g. 'F' if you passed in "E F"), rather than making keys for each value and giving them a value of 1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a couple ways to accomplish this.

First uses [Getopt::Long's built in hash options](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#Options-with-hash-values) but to make it require requires changing how you handle your options.  To say a value is a hash you add a `%`.

```
'suppress:s%' => \$opt{suppress}
```

But Getopt::Long expects multiple values to be passed in with multiple uses of `--suppress`.  This is how many programs do multiple argument handling.

```
program --suppress E --suppress F
```

If you try `--suppress E F` it will read that as `--suppress E` and leave `F` on `@ARGV`.

Furthermore, `%` usually works with `--option key=value`.  In your case `$opt{suppress}{E}` will have no value.  Instead of `if( $opt{suppress}{E} )` you'll have to check `if( exists $opt{suppress}{E} )`.

---

The second option is to use [a user defined function](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Long#User-defined-subroutines-to-handle-options).  This has the advantage of being reusable for multiple options.

```
sub listopt_to_hash {
    my($name, $val) = @_;
    $opt{$name}{$val} = 1;
    return;
}

GetOptions(
    'verbose' => \$opt{verbose},
    'suppress:s{1,}' => \&listopt_to_hash
);
```

---

The final option is to use a different module.  There's [many, many, many Getopt modules on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/search?q=getopt&search_type=modules) and one probably does what you want.

Comment: Thanks! I went with the first option. After reading a bit more into this, I see that's more common than what I wanted to do. Also, my program takes as its primary (non-optional) argument a directory path with no -- switch to denote it, and my approach falls apart if that is given right after the --suppress switches the way I was doing it. The path gets picked up as a suppress hash key.